# Retornar desde INNER JOIN a JSON con PHP

Tags: php, json

Tengo dos tablas relacionadas y cuanto trato de traer esos datos en `JSON` no tengo respuesta y tampoco errores. Si hago la consulta solo de `usuarios`, el resultado es correcto, pero cuando cambio la consulta con `INNER JOIN` no tengo resultados.

tabla usuario

```
| id | nicname | email          | pass
----------------------------------------
| 1  |  pepe   | pepe@mail.com  | 123
| 2  |  laura  | laura@mail.com | 123
| 3  |  nico   | nico@mail.com  | 123
```

tabla perfil

```
| idperfil | userid | direccion  | telefono
--------------------------------------------
|   1      |  1     | calle 1    | 154878987
|   2      |  2     | calle 13   | 564564566
|   3      |  3     | calle 8    | 867823432
```

script

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');

try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=administracion', 'root', '');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "ERROR: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$stmt = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM usuario INNER JOIN perfil ON perfil.userid = usuario.id");
$data = array();

while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    $data[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Agradezco la ayuda de antemano!

Comment: prueba con esto  select * from usuari as u , perfil as p  where  u.id = p.usuerid

Answer (score 1):

Invirte el orden la de las referencis del JOIN

```
INNER JOIN perfil ON perfil.userid = usuario.id
```

por

```
INNER JOIN perfil ON usuario.id = perfil.userid
```

Comment: Porque habría de cambiar el resultado por el orden de los parametros dentro del condicional?